# Docker container running SQL Server seems to crash every time

Tags: docker

I created a Docker container:

```
sudo docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

Then I ran it:

```
sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=root' -p 1401:1433 
                --name sqlserver1 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

I ran:

```
docker start sqlserver1
```

After about 3 seconds `docker ps` returns empty - making me think the container is shutting down.

I'm new to Docker - is this really shutting down automatically? If so, how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I gave this a shot, and it looks as if your problem is not a Docker problem...it's simply a MSSQL problem. If you look at the logs for your container, you'll see:

```
ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password validation failed.
The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is
too short. The password must be at least 8 characters.
```

It looks as if MSSQL enforces password complexity requirements, which include length and number of character classes. The following seems to work fine:

```
docker run -it -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=r00t.R00T' -p 1401:1433 --name sqlserver1 microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```